# java.lang.NullPointerException from control comes from gmail to servlet page

Tags: java

Web.jsp

```html
<form action="SMail" method="post">
   Email: <input type="text" name="email" required /> <br>
   <br> Password: <input type="text" name="psw" required /> <br>
   <br> <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

SMail.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String eemail = request.getParameter("email");
    String spsw = request.getParameter("psw");

    HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
    session1.setAttribute("semail", eemail);

    try {
        String from = "xxx@gmail.com";
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                return new PasswordAuthentication("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");

            }

        });

        // Used to debug SMTP issues
        session.setDebug(true);

        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(eemail));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("Successful Registartion");

        // Now set the actual message
        // message.setText("Hello");
        message.setContent(
                "<h4>Confirmation registration by clicking the below link <br><br> <a href='http://localhost:6335/WebApp/Web'>Click me</a><h4>",
                "text/html");

        System.out.println("sending...");
        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Web.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter w = response.getWriter();

    HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
    w.println(session1.getAttribute("semail").toString());
    System.out.println(session1.getAttribute("semail").toString());
}


java.lang.NullPointerException
at Web.doGet(Web.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1195)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

> I want the session attribute (i.e., email) to be printed in Web.java.
>   But I am getting NullPointer Exception .
>   session attribute is printed when the control does not go to gmail. 
>   Is it becoz when control returned from gmail to Web servlet the session attribute becomes Null
>   Where am I going wrong in code.
>   I have gone my all the solutions but it is not working.
>   Please can someone helped me with proper code to print the session attribute in Web.java

NullPointerException at line:
w.println(session1.getAttribute("semail").toString());

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please condense your code in a [MCVE] so we can better help you!

Comment: According to the stack trace you posted in your question, the `NullPointerException` is occurring on line 71 of file `Web.java`. Which line is that? Maybe [edit] your question and indicate the line in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Session will be the same only if the session cookies are there to identify that session. If the session cookie is not stored by the client, then getSession() will create a new session every time and session.getAttribute() will return null, like in the case you're seeing.

Comment: I tried with cookies it is working fine when control doesn't go to gmail. But when the control is transfered from gmail to web.java servlet then I am getting junk values.

Answer (score 0):

My code is finally working fine. The mistake was I was setting the session attribute in eclipse internal browser (i.e., web.jsp) and since gmail in running in chrome. I trying print the session attribute in chrome browser.
But when I run web.jsp in chrome itself I am finally able to print the session attributes correctly.